# How does ConcurrentHashMap work internally?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, hashmap

I was reading the official Oracle documentation about Concurrency in Java and I was wondering what could be the difference between a `Collection` returned by

```
public static <T> Collection<T> synchronizedCollection(Collection<T> c);
```

and using for example a

`ConcurrentHashMap`. I'm assuming that I use `synchronizedCollection(Collection<T> c)` on a `HashMap`. I know that in general a synchronized collection is essentially just a decorator for my `HashMap` so it is obvious that a `ConcurrentHashMap` has something different in its internals. Do you have some information about those implementation details?

**Edit: I realized that the source code is publicly available:**
[ConcurrentHashMap.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java.html)

Comment: http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/concurrenthashmap-revealed.html

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601 IMHO this is one of the books that every java developer should read :-)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I would read the [source of ConcurrentHashMap](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java.html) as it is rather complicated in the detail. In short it has

- Multiple partitions which can be locked independently. (16 by default)
- Using concurrent Locks operations for thread safety instead of synchronized.
- Has thread safe Iterators. synchronizedCollection's iterators are not thread safe.
- Does not expose the internal locks. synchronizedCollection does.

Comment: Would be useful to provide a link to the source

Comment: For those without a JDK, and IDE or access to google I will add a link. ;)

Comment: I just realized that the source code is available for me. I see that CHM has its own subclass of ReentrantLock for locking. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Yes, one Segment for each partition.  You can increase the number of partitions but you rarely need to (except for some micro-benchmarks ;)

Comment: By partition you mean the buckets? Or this is not implemented with the classic buckets+linked list model?

Comment: btw, ConcurrentHashMapV8+ is quite an improvement, it's available at http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/jsr166e/ConcurrentHashMapV8.java?view=markup

Answer (score 28):

The `ConcurrentHashMap` is very similar to the `java.util.HashTable` class, except that `ConcurrentHashMap` offers better concurrency than `HashTable` or `synchronizedMap` does. `ConcurrentHashMap` does not lock the Map while you are reading from it. Additionally,`ConcurrentHashMap` does not lock the entire `Map`when writing to it. It only locks the part of the `Map` that is being written to, internally.

Another difference is that ConcurrentHashMap does not throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if the `ConcurrentHashMap` is changed while being iterated. The `Iterator` is not designed to be used by more than one thread though whereas `synchronizedMap` may throw `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: @PeterLawrey - seconded. Voted up to redress

Comment: I don't see why did he downvote you either. Voted you up too.

Answer (score 18):

This is the article that helped me understand it [Why ConcurrentHashMap is better than Hashtable and just as good as a HashMap](https://web.archive.org/web/20120321221256/http://www.codercorp.com/blog/java/why-concurrenthashmap-is-better-than-hashtable-and-just-as-good-hashmap.html)

> Hashtable’s offer concurrent access to their entries, with a small caveat, the entire map is locked to perform any sort of operation.
> While this overhead is ignorable in a web application under normal
> load, under heavy load it can lead to delayed response times and
> overtaxing of your server for no good reason.
>
> This is where ConcurrentHashMap’s step in. They offer all the features
> of Hashtable with a performance almost as good as a HashMap.
> ConcurrentHashMap’s accomplish this by a very simple mechanism.
> Instead of a map wide lock, the collection maintains a list of 16
> locks by default, each of which is used to guard (or lock on) a single
> bucket of the map. This effectively means that 16 threads can modify
> the collection at a single time (as long as they’re all working on
> different buckets). Infact there is no operation performed by this
> collection that locks the entire map. The concurrency level of the
> collection, the number of threads that can modify it at the same time
> without blocking, can be increased. However a higher number means more
> overhead of maintaining this list of locks.

Comment: Link is dead, but [it is still accessible it through the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120321221256/http://www.codercorp.com/blog/java/why-concurrenthashmap-is-better-than-hashtable-and-just-as-good-hashmap.html)

Comment: @LaurentBourgault-Roy, cheers edited answer to reflect this

Answer (score 5):

The "scalability issues" for `Hashtable` are present in exactly the same way in `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)` - they use very simple synchronization, which means that only one thread can access the map at the same time.

This is not much of an issue when you have simple inserts and lookups (unless you do it extremely intensively), but becomes a big problem when you need to iterate over the entire Map, which can take a long time for a large Map - while one thread does that, all others have to wait if they want to insert or lookup anything.

The `ConcurrentHashMap` uses very sophisticated techniques to reduce the need for synchronization and allow parallel read access by multiple threads without synchronization and, more importantly, provides an Iterator that requires no synchronization and even allows the Map to be modified during interation (though it makes no guarantees whether or not elements that were inserted during iteration will be returned).

Answer (score 4):

Returned by *synchronizedCollection()* is an object all methods of which are synchronized on *this*, so all concurrent operations on such wrapper are serialized. ConcurrentHashMap is a truly concurrent container with fine grained locking optimized to keep contention as low as possible. Have a look at the source code and you will see what it is inside.

Answer (score -2):

ConcurrentHashMap implements ConcurrentMap which provides the concurrency.
Deep internally its iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time which maintains the synchronization.
This map is used widely in concurrency.