# How to avoid ConcurrentModificationException in multi-threaded code

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

Whenever we use java.util Collection classes, we have that if one thread changes a collection while another thread is traversing through it using an iterator, then any call to `iterator.hasNext()` or `iterator.next()` will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. Even the `synchronized` collection wrapper classes `SynchronizedMap` and `SynchronizedList` are only conditionally thread-safe, which means all individual operations are thread-safe but compound operations where flow of control depends on the results of previous operations may be subject to threading issues. The question is: How to avoid this problem without affecting the performance. Note: I am aware of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: Then you already know your solution. You can't have your cake and eat it too: concurrent access entails a concurrent structure.

Comment: It is very case specific and the way you are using one. Also there needs to be consideration why you can not make the collection access and modification synchronized.

Comment: What is your **concrete** problem? You are talking about generic issues.

Comment: I would return a copy of collection for `Iteration` same as what `CopyOnWriteArrayList` does

Comment: I often (but not always) use CopyOnWriteArrayList to solve these type of problems. However sometimes it can be extremely costly. With this question I just would like to hear some opinions and alternatives addressing this issue. I will accept the answer that I see as a better (generic) alternative.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655362/concurrentmodificationexception-despite-using-synchronized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or `ConcurrentHashMap` etc. as you mentioned above or you can use `Atomic*` classes which are working with CAS.

If you weren't aware of `Atomic*` classes they definitely worth a look! You may check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664172/java-concurrency-cas-vs-locking) question.

So to answer your question you have to choose the right tools for the task. Since you do not share the context with us I can just guess. In some situations CAS will perform better in others the concurrent Collections will.

If something isn't clear you can always check out the official Oracle Trails: [Lesson: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: Not sure how a ConcurrentHashMap will help him, as the locks there are on segments of the map.

Comment: The `synchronized` decorator classes he mentioned are locking the whole `Map`. `ConcurrentHashMap` in the other hand only locks a bucket and only if you modify/delete.

Comment: @Adam Arold - I understand, but I think it might be too risky. If I remember correctly, the synchronized decorator does not uses a RW-Lock, but uses "synchronized", this is why I suggested to lock but with RWLock at my comment.

Comment: I see. Well it is hard to come up with a single case where those decorators are good.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the "standard" Java collections are not thread safe as they are not synchronized. When working with multiple threads accessing your collections, you should look at the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) packages.

Without this package, before Java 5, one had to perform a manual synchronization :

```
synchronized(list) {
   Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
   while (i.hasNext())
       foo(i.next());
}
```

or using

```
Collections.synchronizedList(arrayList);
```

but neither could really offer a complete thread safety feature.

With this package, all access to the collection is made atomically and some classes `provide a snapshot of the state of the list when the iterator was constructed` (see [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#iterator%28%29). The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is fast on read, but if you are performing many writes, this might affect performance.

Thus, if `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is not desired, take a look at [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) which offers `a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw ConcurrentModificationException, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator`. This one is efficient in all point, unless you have to access elements at specific indexes more often than traversing the entire collection.

Another option would be [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) which `provides expected average log(n) time cost for the contains, add, and remove operations and their variants. Insertion, removal, and access operations safely execute concurrently by multiple threads` and `iterators are weakly consistent` as well.

Which concurrent (thread-safe) collections depend of what type of operations you perform the most with. And since they are all part of the Java Collection framework, you can swap them to which ever you need.

Comment: The comment is too general. You should have specified which classes could help him. java.util.concurrent is not a magic solution for concurrency if you don't know how to use it well

Comment: OP is already aware not only of the package, but of the specific class that solves his problem. @AmitD This wouldn't fare well even as a comment :) For the record, Yanick, I'm not one of your downvoters.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` nitice. The answer was amended.

Answer (score 1):

I think you raised an interesting question. 
I tried thinking whether ConcurrentHashMap for example, as was suggested by others can help, but I'm not sure as the lock is segment-based. 
What I would do in this case , and I do hope I understood your question well, is to lock access to your collection, using a [ReaderWriterLock.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) 
The reason I chose this lock is because I do feel this needs locking (as you explained - iteration is composed from several operations) , 
And because in case of reader threads, I do not want them to wait on lock , if no writer thread is working on the collection.
Thanks to @Adam Arold I paid attention that you suggested the "synchronized decorator" - but I feel this decorator is "too strong" for your needs, as it uses a synchronized and will not diffrentiate between cases of N readers and M writers.

Comment: Read my question about `ConcurrentHashMap`s: [How does ConcurrentHashMap works internally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793067/how-does-concurrenthashmap-works-internally)

Comment: @Adam Arold -thanks for pointing out this question. I learnt new things. The only problem (as I can see it)) is you're limiting him to a Map (or let's say - ConcurrentMap) interface. I would try to find a more generic solution, if possible, but you are right in other comments - it really depends on your needs.

Comment: For generic solutions you can check out Atomic* classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unencapsulated `Collection` object of a non thread-safe class, it is impossible to prevent misuse of the `Collection`, and thus [the possibility of a `ConcurrentModificationException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/why-is-a-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown).

Other answers have suggested use of a thread-safe `Collection` class, such as those provided by `java.util.concurrent`. You should however [consider encapsulating the `Collection` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55141359/545127): have the object be `private`, and have your class provide higher level abstractions (such as `addPerson` and `removePerson`) that manipulate the `Collection` on behalf of the callers, and do not have any getter methods that return references to the `Collection`. It is then fairly easy to enforce invariants on the encapsulated data (such as "every person has a non empty name") *and* provide thread-safety using `synchronized`.