# Is ConcurrentHashMap analogy to CopyOnWriteArrayList

Tags: java

I use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` quite alot. This is especially true when

- Threads perform a lot of read
- Threads perform a little of write

However, I will use `Collections.synchronizedList()` when

- Threads perform a little of read
- Threads perform a lot of write

This is because according to [CopyOnWriteArrayList Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

> A thread-safe variant of ArrayList in which all mutative operations
>   (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the
>   underlying array.
>
> This is ordinarily too costly, ...

When comes to `ConcurrentHashMap`, I was wondering can I still apply the same logic in choosing `ConcurrentHashMap` over `Collections.synchronizedMap()`?

**Does `ConcurrentHashMap` make a fresh copy of underlying data structure, every-time I perform write operation? Will it perform badly than Collections.synchronizedMap, if there is more write operation than read?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793067/how-does-concurrenthashmap-work-internally

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `ConcurrentHashMap` does not make a fresh copy of underlying data structure.

`ConcurrentHashMap` is a segmented map, number of segments are based on concurrency level. And when you write to a segment, then it gets locked until write is complete.

Answer (score 1):

`ConcurrentHashMap` is almost always the right one to use as it has better performance and more useful API (you can avoid the `check-then-set` thread problem) than its counterparts
It uses *lock stripping* for finer grained access and does not copy the map.
The **only** application where you should not use a `ConcurrentHashMap` is when you would need to lock the map for **exclusive access**.

Comment: Ya. I know that. But that doesn't address my question yet. Does ConcurrentHashMap make a fresh copy of underlying data structure, every-time I perform write operation?

Comment: First of all why do you care about what it does if the performance is documented as best than its counterparts? No, it does not copy.It uses lock stripping to modify parts of the underlying map

Comment: Because CopyOnWriteArrayList perform badly than its counterpart Collections.synchronizedList when there is more write than read operation. Hence, I care whether such behavior occurs in ConcurrentHashMap too.

Comment: `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is best choice when the dominant access you do is a traversal of the list.Otherwise it is not the best choice. Additionally `ConcurrentHashMap` is recommended by `Bloch` and `Goetz` as optimal in performance.

Comment: I would use a synchronized collection is you typically expect only one thread to be using it but you need thread safety just in case.  I would use the concurrent collections where you expect some contention between threads some of the time.

Answer (score 1):

When writing to `ConcurrentHashMap`.It only locks the part of the Map, internally, that is being written to.So by this behaviour , we can eaisly see that it doesnot make the fresh copy but make changes in same copy.
So when we try to write in `ConcurrentHashMap` then it means we are trying to write in any segment then it just lock that segment as well as update only that segment.So in simple words , it **Never ever** makes any fresh copy. So the answer of your question is **NO.**

Answer (score 0):

The major difference I found is the custom 'concurrency level' in ConcurrentHashMap. 
We can ask JVM in how many chunks(segments) it need to divide the Map. Those many locks will be created. 
CopyOnWriteArrayList uses simple process of simply creating a clone and updating it. (This is later merged with original arraylist by JVM.)