# What is the difference between Segment of ConcurrentHashMap and buckets of HashMap theoretically?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I understand that in HashMap, the entries (Key, Value) are placed in buckets based on hash(`Key.hashCode`)--> The index that denotes the bucket location. In case an entry is already placed at that location, there is a linked list created and the new entry (if it has a different key --> via `equals()` method) is placed at the beginning of the linked list.

1. Can I co-relate this concept with that of ConcurrentHashMap, but instead of Buckets, there are Segments upon which individual threads have a lock. And instead of Entries, there are HashEntry(ies). In similar fashion, a linked list is created and if the Key-Value pair being inserted is different, based on `equals()` of the key, it is placed at end of the linked list.
2. Am I correct when I say that:
   `put` of CHM is not synchronized, thus any thread can access this method, this put method calculates hash value of the key passed to it and gets the segment index (kind of like buckets). Then for that segment only, it calls the `put` method. Now under Segment, the `put` method specifies that there will be a `lock()`, so that only one thread can alter data in a particular segment, thus concluding that if the concurrency level is 16 there shall be 16 threads and thus these threads will be able to **PUT** values only one segment at a time.

Comment: This might help [How does ConcurrentHashMap work internally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793067/how-does-concurrenthashmap-work-internally)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. A bucket is an individual slot in the map's array. This is the same with both `HashMap` and `ConcurrentHashMap`. Conceptually, the latter has its array broken into segments (each segment is an array of references), but that's it. Note that the CHM in Java 8 no longer has segments, it's all a single array.
2. Yes, it's the scheme known as *segmented locking*. It reduces inter-thread contention, but does not eliminate it.

Comment: For pt. 1 in your answer : Does that mean that the buckets in CHM are divided too? And under those segments there are HashEntry linked lists?

Comment: Buckets cannot be divided, they are linked lists. A segment is a bucket array, there's just more of them per one map instance.

Comment: But the structure as i saw in code is like:

CHM has an instance of Segment
Segment has an instance of HashEntry

Where does the bucket come into picture

Comment: I guess you saw wrong, both are arrays. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#169  and   http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#307

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say that there is an array of Segment in CHM and an array of HashEntry in Segment. Now you said that "A segment is a bucket array"? Please elaborate on that.

Comment: Segment = array of HashEntry. One HashEntry = one bucket. Does that clear your vision?