# in ConcurrentHashMAP , why HashEntry was introduced in Java 7 at first place and why it was removed in JDK8?

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to understand the implementation of ConcurrentHashMAP (CHM) , BUT it looks like a huge difference in Java 7 and Jav8 Implementation of CHM,

1) I am trying to start understanding with the very first question why HashEntry was introduced in Java 7 at first place and why it was removed in JDK8?

2) What factor define the table size in CHM, is it concurrenylevel or capacity ?

```
/**
 * Stripped-down version of helper class used in previous version,
 * declared for the sake of serialization compatibility
 */
static class Segment<K,V> extends ReentrantLock implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2249069246763182397L;
    final float loadFactor;
    Segment(float lf) { this.loadFactor = lf; }
}
```

3) is concurrency level playing two roles?

one is to sizing the table and then deciding the number of concurrent Thread who can update he map? what is the role of concurrencylevel in internal implementation of CHM i.e. how number of thread are limited using this variable value, what part of implementation dictate this ?

Comment: Is this part of the public API (as in, is it in the Javadoc)? If not, it's just an implementation detail, and can be changed at any time.

Comment: I understand that implementation may change, just try to understand why they changed it again ? and please if you can help with answer of other question too ?

Comment: the OpenJDK mailing list will probably contain the historical context.

Comment: Besides, it wasn't "introduced" in Java 7.  The `ConcurrentHashMap.HashEntry` class was present in Java 6 ... and probably earlier.

Comment: @Stephen C  , may be you are right, I wanted to make a point that why it is removed ?

Comment: @Rex - that is not a "point".  It is a question.  The answer is that the hashmap classes were largely rewritten to improve performance in Java 8, and this happened as part of that rewrite.  In order to understand the precise reasons for this particular change, you would need to either do a forensic analysis of the complete implementation ... or ask the Oracle programmers who did the work.  And the answer could simply be that they preferred it that way.

Comment: @StephenC I thought we are discussing  technology here , but I think you like discussing English literature more, anyway thanks for trying . I was also going to that direction, that if it is just rename then why they are just renaming internal structure and making us confused in comparative analysis ? or I am really missing any important "purpose of change" ?

Comment: *"I was also going to that direction, that if it is just rename then why they are just renaming internal structure and making us confused in comparative analysis ? or I am really missing any important "purpose of change"?"*  - Now you are asking a philosophical or psychological question.  Why do they change things?  For a good reason?  For no good reason?  The only way to *really* know is to ask **them**.

Comment: And that is the problem with your question.  You are essentially expecting *us* to know why *they* made decisions.  We don't know.  We *can't* know.   And even if someone *thinks they know* ... it is at best a theory, an opinion.   Questions that require an opinion-based answer are off-topic.

Comment: @Stephen C This is the beauty of Open source technology that you got know the reason of every "why". if  i would have asked you that why they removed PermGen in Java8,I am sure you would have answered , bcz you know the logic behind, and then you wouldn't have talked that much. Just because you don't know answer of something, it doesn't mean that "problem is in  question". may be some1 else know the answer and can help here.That is what stackOverflow for.You always can choose not to answer if you don't know the answer. It's not philosophy, just science,tht u might not understand sometime.

Comment: Nope.  The only way to understand the reason why someone made a particular choice out of a number of alternatives is to ask them.  The source code doesn't tell you what they were thinking.

Comment: And regard Permgen, the answer is the same.  We don't understand the real reasons why they did it.  I'm sure they were good reasons, but they were most likely complicated ... and not something that would be possible to understand if you weren't at the internal planning meetings.   Trying to reverse engineer the reasons / thought process is NOT science.  It is pure guesswork.

Comment: @StephenC https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/about-g1-garbage-collector,-permanent-generation-and-metaspace  , this may help you understand the PrmGen removal reason. As I said , It's pure science, no guess. sometime have to put more effort to understand things but everything in science has a logic. let's keep digging  until we get the rock !!!

Comment: So do your own research. Find the blog or mailing list postings that explains this. Clearly you have the time. And when you have found it, post your own answer. But note that you didn't find the permgen information by looking at the source.  You had to rely on the author's explanations.  And I predict that in this case, you will too.

Comment: you were reading answers from oracle official site , and you are still talking all this. I think you enjoy talking anything but  Technology. I hope there is a way to filter talkative people like you from answering questions. Sorry to say but what a wastage of  time , discussing with you . I tried helping you but you are not ready to listen. I am done here. keep talking !!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you dont have full understanding of ConcurrentHashMap and the intent behind its introduction. It was introduced to accomplish concurrent read and write operation with minimal locking. Using ConcurrentHashMap, one is able to lock different parts of map simultaneously. In Java 8, they have made ConcurrentHashMap more lock-free.

Concurrencylevel plays important role in deciding various attribute values for ConcurrentHashMap .

1) I am trying to start understanding with the very first question why HashEntry was introduced in Java 7 at first place and why it was removed in JDK8?

Answer - Are you sure it is removed? It is probably still there under segments. Please see below -

[ConcurrentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331484/what-is-the-difference-between-segment-of-concurrenthashmap-and-buckets-of-hashm)

2) What factor define the table size in CHM, is it concurrenylevel or capacity ?

Answer - Concurrencylevel decides everything. Default concurrencylevel is 16 or 32. You can set it programmatically also.

3) is concurrency level playing two roles? one is to sizing the table and then deciding the number of concurrent Thread who can update he map?

Answer - YES. It provides hint for sizing. Generally number of segments and concurrent threads are limited to this number.

what is the role of concurrencylevel in internal implementation of CHM i.e. how number of thread are limited using this variable value, what part of implementation dictate this ?

You can check oracle documentation.

[CocurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html)

For further reference -

[Java 8 ConcurrentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460503/java-8-concurrenthashmap)

Comment: I am adding the Segment class Code for reference in my question section , I can't see any HashEntry there.  can you please check ? And yes You are right, I don't have full understanding of CHM , that is why I think I am here asking questions and seeking help :) Thanks for help.